# telerik rad grid filer icon dispaly as square

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik-grid, telerik-open-access

Filter icon in telerik grid display as squere it not showing balck icon inside it.
I used here telerik EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" properties.

[image]

I needed icon like below

[image]

Comment: Can you inspect the element and see if the styling is applied for the item? Not sure what icon you're expecting there. Check to make sure all class files are loading and they aren't blocked, and finally make sure some other custom styling isn't overriding your expect icon styling.

Comment: Larry Bud... if I remove EnableEmbeddedBaseStylesheet="false" EnableEmbeddedSkins="false" these properties know then it show icon..

Comment: Using those properties means you're disabling the built in styles and skins. The default is for them to be included.